# How can I get the next letter alphabetically without incrementing? (php)

Tags: php, increment, letters

```
for ($i=A;$i<L;$i++){                   
    echo $i;
    echo '->';
    echo ++$i;
    echo ', ';
}
```

gives me:

> A->B, C->D, E->F, G->H, I->J, K->L

what I want is:

> A->B, B->C, C->D, D->E, E->F, F->G

What's the simplest way to do this?

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Bad idea. `++` works also for incrementing strings in PHP.  `+ 1` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just copying the value before incrementing it:

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i < 'L'; $i++) {                   
    $j = $i;
    $j++;
    echo "$i->$j, ";
}
```

Ps. You really should quote your string constants.  Otherwise your logs will be full of warnings like these:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant A - assumed 'A' in - on line 2
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant L - assumed 'L' in - on line 2
```

Comment: THis is what I ended up doing although these other ones would work too.

Answer (score 7):

Simple:

```
for ($i=A;$i<L;){  // remove loop increment                 
    echo $i;
    echo '->';
    echo ++$i;
    echo ', ';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use range() to get the alphabet as an array then use a proper int i++ incrementation.

Answer (score 1):

As Julien mentioned, range is sexy for this:

```
$range = range('A', 'L');

// Had to subtract one from loop iteration total, otherwise the $i + 1 
// would throw an undefined index notice
for ($i = 0, $count = count($range); $i < ($count - 1); $i++) {
    echo sprintf('%s->%s,', $range[$i], $range[($i + 1)]);
}
```

More info on [range](https://www.php.net/range).